# Remove Linux Adobe Acrobat Reader installed from binary

Tags: linux, debian, uninstall, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

On a Debian system, I installed Adobe Acrobat Reader using the Linux binary (`AdbeRdr9.4.2-1_i486linux_enu.bin`) downloaded from Adobe's website. What's the right way to uninstall Reader when it was installed this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Adobe Acrobat Reader is installed under `/opt`.  If so, you should run:

```
# /opt/Adobe/bin/UNINSTALL
```

If this file should not exist, install over the previous installation with the newest .bin from Adobe and the file should appear.